OOM killer destroys not only my python program with memory loss - but terminal emulator also
In short, I can't figure out how to set up the killer's OOM so that it doesn't kill the kitty terminal, in case the terminal's child process suddenly starts bullying.
Apparently, OOM-killer mistakenly decided that if a child process starts eating memory without stopping, then this is a reason to kill not only this particular child process, but also its parent. This problem appeared when I ran a python script in the terminal with an error that causes non-stop memory allocation.
the most interesting thing is that when I ran the same script in gnome terminal, instead of the terminal crashing, I received the message killed, and the terminal itself calmly continued to work.
It seems that gnome-terminal is registered somewhere in the killer's OOM settings as a trusted and good process that should not be killed, even if its child processes turn out to be clearly bad. And that's why I would like to at least find out how to register kitty in this trusted list.

Are you sure there isn't some sort of memory leak in this kitty terminal thing that causes it to be killed as well? I really doubt there will be any "OOM setting" here, it seems more likely to depend on how the different programs work.

How much memory and how much swap space have you got in that machine?

Do you have swap? free will tell you and us.  If not, you need between 1xRAM and 2xRAM. Please [edit] your Question to add this information.  Do not use Add Comment.

Do you have swap? free will tell you and us.  If not, you need between 1xRAM and 2xRAM. Please [edit] your Question to add this information.  Do not use Add Comment.

FWIW: Recently installed Ubuntu 24.04 on a 4TB NVME; free tells: 16G RAM, 4G Swap  (NOT partitioned by me / manually)
